# How make modeling from train and test data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the order file,

```
#split into train and test sets
X = DataFrame.values
train_size = int(len(X)*0.66)
train, test = X[1:train_size], X[train_size:]
train_X, train_y = train[:,0], train[:,1]
test_X, test_y = test[:,0], test[:,1]
```

I want train_data to test data in different files by calling.

```
def test(learning_rate=0.1, k=1, training_epochs=15):
    print ('... loading data')
    datasets = ('book-sales.csv')
    train_X, train_y = datasets[0]
    test_X, test_y = datasets[0]
    print ('... modeling')
    rbm = RBM(input=train_X, n_visible=28 * 28, n_hidden=500)
```

I tried but I found this message.

> train_X, train_y = datasets[0]
>
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

How should I write it?

Comment: Please add relevant tags next time. I've added this one for you.

Comment: I'm still do not understand... @zipa do i need to write it like that?

Comment: btw, thats operator boolean? @zipa

Comment: You night want to use `scikit-learn` library (included in Pandas) which includes several functions for splitting data into train/test

Comment: Well, I must be more to learn it ... thanks @SembeiNorimaki

Answer (score 0):

When you have to read a dataset directly in a file, it is recommended to use the library `pandas` http://pandas.pydata.org/ because it has been designed for data analysis:

```
import pandas as pd
data_path = "./book-sales.csv" #path to access data
datasets = pd.read_csv(data_path)
```

`datasets` object has now the `DataFrame` pandas type.

Plus, depending on the actual form of your dataset, you may want to use the get_values method `datasets.get_values()`, and reshape for better convenience.

That way, you can split your data into train and test sets.

Hope this could be helpfull

Comment: this is very helpful, I will learn it. thanks @Nathaniel Saura

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to split the dataframe into two random samples (80% and 20%) for training and testing in Python by using :

```
import pandas as pd
data_path = "./book-sales.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(data_path)
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
train_X, train_y= df[msk]
test_X, test_y= df[~msk]
```

Comment: for df, how i must define?

Comment: I've edited the answer , you read df from csv and then split into train and test data sets .

Comment: oh ya, i'ts work, thank you @saghe Achraf but i added df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2)) from a reference. do you know what function (100, 2)?

Comment: happy that worked . Please up vote the answer . See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html for more details about randn function .